# Adapter deployment failure with "main javascript file is missing"

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

I have built a TestAdapter.adapter file. When I deploy it on local environment it works properly, but when I try deploying it on production server I get the following error:

> The 'TestAdapter-impl.js' main javascript file is missing.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: What do you see in the messages.log file of the production application server at the time of error?

Comment: Waiting for your response.

Comment: messages.log had the same exact error in it, I managed the figure out the cause, the deployment team ran the .adapter files through an aggressive anti-virus software which has removed the Javascript content from the adapter files as a security precaution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the deployment team ran the .adapter files through an aggressive anti-virus software which has removed the Javascript content from the adapter files as a security precaution, disabling the anti-virus software fixed the problem.